# Sum time using java in HH:MM format

Tags: java, datetime, time

I am trying to add the daily working hours for an employee for a duration of a week.

Ex: if an employee worked as Below in `HH:MM` format

```
Monday      09:45
Tuesday     10:00
Wednesday   09:00
Thursday    09:30
Friday      10:00
----------------------------
Total       48:15
----------------------------
```

I need to sum the week timings to generate payroll hours. How I could do this using java.

Could you please help with this ? thanks a lot !!

Comment: What code have you got so far? What objects / classes are you dealing with?

Comment: I often use JodaTime for DateTime stuff in Java, take a loot at http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html#parse(java.lang.String, org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormatter)

Comment: Thanks, Andrew for responding. I am using `Date` object with `SimpleDateFormat`. But i am getting incorrect results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd put it like that:

```
int sum = 0
for( String hhmm : workingTimes ){
  String[] split = hhmm.split( ":", 2 );
  int mins = Integer.valueOf(split[ 0 ]) * 60 + Integer.valueOf( split[ 1 ] );
  sum += mins;
}

String formattedWorkingTime = (int)Math.floor(sum/60) + ":" + ( sum % 60 );
```

Comment: Working perfect. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
public static String totalTime(String...times) {
    int total = 0;
    for (String time : times) {
        String[] splits = time.split(":");
        total+=(Integer.parseInt(splits[0])*60 + Integer.parseInt(splits[1]));
    }

    return total/60 + ":" + total%60;
}
```

or

Alternatively You can also use [Java 8 Time API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)